# Xpages SSJS Create Administration Process

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

Has anyone been able to get SSJS CreateAdministrationProcess to work?  I have searched for functioning code but was not able to find any.

I am trying to create an adminP request in SSJS to set a users password. I can't use the ?changepassword in the url method because we do not allow web users access to the NAB.

I am using OAUTH and when I try to hash and update the password directly to the NAB it without an adminp request, it creates problems with the current client session, logging them out and then locking them out.

I assume this is because I changed the credential tokens on the server but not on the client and when it realizes this it thinks I'm trying to authenticate over and over and locks me out.

If I can't get the SSJS to work I am going to write it in a lotusscript agent and call the agent from SSJS, but for posterity sake I wanted to get AdminP requests to work from SSJS directly.

Here is my code:

```
var hashednew = session.hashPassword(thenewpw)
nabDoc.replaceItemValue("HTTPPassword",hashednew)
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today 12");
nabDoc.replaceItemValue("HTTPPasswordChangeDate",dt)
dt.recycle()
var nabServerAccessView:NotesView = nabDB.getView("($ServerAccess)")
nabDB.DelayUpdates = false;
var AdminP=sessionAsSigner.CreateAdministrationProcess("abcServerName/Co")
var AdminPNoteId=AdminP.SetUserPasswordSettings(@Name("[ABBREVIATE]" ,@UserName()), 0, 0, 0, True)
nabDoc.save(true,true)
nabServerAccessView.refresh()
```

It is crashing at the line:

```
var AdminP=sessionAsSigner.CreateAdministrationProcess("abcServerName/Co")
```

and the server error is:

```
Error calling method 'CreateAdministrationProcess(string)' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.Session [Static Java Interface Wrapper, lotus.domino.local.Session: lotus.d
```

AS A FOLLOWUP,

The original code I posted had more than the uppercase/lowercase issue, in practice.  I was able to get it to work, but the way I was updating to the NAB directly was wrong.  I found a better way to do the password change using SSJS with the following snippet, and it's pretty simple.  Of course you have to validate the old password and complexity of the new password first, but once you've done that you can run the following:

```
try {
var AdminP=sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess.createAdministrationProcess(server)
var chgPW=AdminP.changeHTTPPassword(theuser,theoldpw,thenewpw)
} catch(e) {print("AdminProcess configure error: " + e)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is in naming convention - Java methods start with lower case letters.

```
var AdminP=sessionAsSigner.createAdministrationProcess("abcServerName/Co")
var AdminPNoteId=AdminP.setUserPasswordSettings(@Name("[ABBREVIATE]" ,@UserName()), 0, 0, 0, True)
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks, I will make sure to review upper/lower cases on code better.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ACL settings: Is "Maximum internet name and password" set to "Manager" or "Designer"?

Comment: Does your user has the correct access to create AdminP requests if you try it from an LS agent ?

Comment: yes, the problem was the code had first letter uppercase, should have been lowercase (createAdministrationProcess).  Thanks.